# Remote setup Whatsapp web and exposed via API

Tags: api, instance, whatsapp

I have seen some providers on internet where you can send Whatsapp messages using an API. Its not official WA API integration.

These providers will spawn a instance for you, show you a QR code. You need to scan the QR code in your WA app. Once scan is completed, that instance is added as linked device in your app.

Now they provide an API which you can use to send messages. API accepts instanceId, mobile number and message as query param.

These messages are send using your WA account and number. You can see those sent messages in your app.

Basically everything is happening from your account via web whatsapp but from a remote setup and using an API.

Here are a screenshot to help you understand what I am trying to convey.

[image]

Sample API call:

https://DOMAIN-HERE/api/send.php?number=84XXXXxxx&type=text&message=test%20message&instance_id=6XXXXXXXXXX&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX

I want to setup something similar. I searched the Internet on how does this work and how I can create my own similar setup but could not find anything.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes. I did something similar. Partially. Here is the blog of what I did - https://pythoncircle.com/post/775/automating-whatsapp-web-using-selenium-to-send-messages/  and next article.

Answer (score 0):

What all these providers are doing is hosting a running instance of a whatsapp web client using your phone number, this is why they ask you to scan the QR code (same as whatsapp web does).

Users of this kind of services must be crazy to allow running an unattended instance of whatsapp against their own phone account, as on the host there's full access to your whatsapp encryption keys, contacts, history of messages,... but the security implications are for a different topic.

If you want to have a headless instance of whatsapp-web like the one they offer, you should have a look at repos like this one here: https://github.com/tulir/whatsmeow (there are others similar, for different languages).

Comment: can you suggest the similar repos with PHP or Laravel ? which can work through API call, and upon scanning QR code return me the authToken and number of the authenticated user ?